# How do you pass a JSON Array from a UITableViewCell into a new UIViewController programmatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uitableview

Here's what I've figured out so far:

**FirstViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface FirstViewController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>

@end
```

**FirstViewController.m**

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"
#import "CellDetailView.h"

@interface FirstViewController()
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *myMutableArray;
@end

- (void)viewDidLoad{
  //...
}

//There's a JSON method here that's working just fine populating the UITableViewCells as intended.
//        ...JSON URL STUFF...
//        [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError){
//        NSError *errorJson = nil;
//        NSDictionary *dataDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&errorJson];
        self.coolDict = [dataDictionary objectForKey:@"coolStuff"];
        self.myMutableArray = [self.coolDict objectForKey:@"stuff_1"];
        [self.tableView reloadData];



//UITableViewCell method here, works great!



- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
    CellDetailView *nextViewController = [[CellDetailView alloc] init]; //This is a UIViewController Class I made.
    NSDictionary *someInfo = self.myMutableArray[indexPath.row];  // This is logging the array for each cell, that's cool.
    NSLog(@"%@", someInfo);
    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:nextViewController animated:YES];
}
```

**CellDetailView.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "FirstViewController.h"

@interface CampaignItemDetails : UIViewController

@end
```

**CellDetailView.m**

```
#import "CellDetailView.h"
#import "FirstViewController.h"

@interface CellDetailView ()
@end

@implementation CellDetailView


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
UILabel *myDetailLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
myDetailLabel.text = someInfo[@"title"];
[self.view addSubview:myDetailLabel];  //THIS DOESNT WORK :(
}

@end
```

How do I get myMutableArray into CellDetailView so I can populate the ViewController with more of this JSON data from the array?

*I know the idea is to push to the CellDetailView (and *not* to pull from FirstViewController).*

I have seen an answer on how to pass data from view controller to view controller but it's very abstract and I'm pretty new to objective C. I've also found a TON of stuff with Storyboards and Nibs, but I'm not using either of those things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd be tempted to override the initMethod like so:

```
 NSDictionary *someInfo = self.myMutableArray[indexPath.row]; 
 CellDetailView *nextViewController = [[CellDetailView alloc] initWithInfo:someInfo];
 [[self navigationController] pushViewController:nextViewController animated:YES];
```

In your cellDetailView make sure you add the init Mehtod:

```
- (id) initWithInfo:(NSDictionary *) info {

    self = [super init];

    if (self) {

       //Now you can save the info to a private NSDictionary property:

    }

    return self;
}
```

Make sure you add:

```
- (id) initWithInfo:(NSDictionary *) info;
```

In your cellDetailView .h.

Comment: Dude. Yes. This is out of control how fast you answered and it worked perfectly. Side question, I had a navigationcontroller in the viewdidload on CellDetailView.m but its gone now. Does initWithInfo become some super view or something? Sorry if that's too vague, I can clarify if you need me to.

Comment: What do you mean by gone ? The navigation bar isn't present ?

Comment: It was present before I added the init Method, now its not showing up.

Comment: Have you removed the old init method ? It should receive the navigation controller from your FirstViewController. Does this have a nav bar ?

Comment: My fault... I was adding subviews to the init method that were covering everything else up. So dumb of me. It's all fixed now and you have helped me in a huge way! Thank you.

Comment: No problems. Happy coding :-)

Answer (score 1):

Use this code in your didSelectRowAtIndexPath

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
    CellDetailView *nextViewController = [[CellDetailView alloc] init]; //This is a UIViewController Class I made.
    NSDictionary *someInfo = self.myMutableArray[indexPath.row];  // This is logging the array for each cell, that's cool.
    NSLog(@"%@", someInfo);

    nextViewController.info = someInfo; //You should define info property in your next controller
    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:nextViewController animated:YES];
}
```

You should define info property in your next controller

```
@interface CellDetailView : UIViewCintroller
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDictionary *info;
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can create DelegateMethod in Your Cell Class.

in Your TableViewCell.h file

```
@protocol CellDelegate <NSObject>
-(void)passJSONArray:(JSONArray *)jsonArray;
@end

@property(nonatomic, assign)id<ButtonCellDelegate> delegate;
```

in Your TableViewCell.m file

create method for send JsonArray.

on JSONArray Getter Method OR In Method Which You get array

You can call sendJSONArray()
like

```
 -(NSArray *)gotMYJSONArray;
 {
    //getJsonArray
    [self sendJSONArray:jsonArray];
    return jsonArray;
 }

-(void)sendJSONArray(JSONArray *)jsonArray
{
   if([_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(passJSONArray:)])
    {
        [_delegate passJSONArray:jsonArray];
    }
}
```

OnYour ViewController

```
-(void)passJSONArray:(JSONArray *)array
{
    self.jsonArray = array;
}
```